# NaSC crashes with xml-error

Tags: release-freya, applications

I installed this little math program called [NaSC](https://launchpad.net/nasc).
When I want to "Open sheets", the app just crashes. 
Nobody else seems to have this problem when using NaSC - at least, nobody seems to have filed any bug reports for it on Launchpad.

So I guess the problem is on the elementary OS side of things?

The error I get from the Terminal is:

```
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/paul/.qalculate/definitions/datasets/elements.xml"
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

So my noob-guess was, I'd just *create* that file in this folder. No luck.
Any ideas?

System is up-to-date elementary OS Freya 0.3.1 64bit

Comment: Hey, strange. The mentioned file is not the problem. Can you run it from terminal with: `nasc --debug` and post the output.

Comment: First guess. You started nasc with root rights on the first run and now it can't read the file. `~/.local/share/nasc/nasc.sheets`
Try to delete it and start it again

Comment: Hm, I think I "kinda-solved" it. I deleted all the content of "My first sheet" and after that, I could create new sheets without crashing. But I still get the above-mentioned errormessages, sometimes with with a different file mentioned: planets.xml. Bottom line: works for me now - so far.

Comment: You should probably remove all files of NaSC first, then reinstall and make sure to not run NaSC as root again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the file `~/.local/share/nasc/nasc.sheets`

Start NaSC again after you deleted this file.